# List all directory using shell command without using find, busybox command

Tags: android, linux, bash, shell

I am working on android shell. which is actually linux shell only but it is not supporting lots of linux standard command.

My requirement is to list all the directory present in particular directory recursively without using find, busybox, egrep. Because these things are not supported in android.

I tried

> ls -R | grep ./

which is giving me output but adding : at the end.

Is there any other way to list all the directory recursively.

Comment: You better install busybox if you haven't yet. Busybox is open-source and is [easy to have](http://busybox.net/downloads/binaries/latest/busybox-armv6l). Never download it from the store.

Answer (score 2):

You can do something like this

```
ls -R | grep ./ | cut -f1 -d:
```

Comment: cut might not be available everywhere

Comment: ya cut is not available on android@jayesh

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps `find` does exist as a busybox builtin but it doesn't exist as a link. Try:

```
busybox find dir -type d
```

Update: Best solution is to [install busybox](http://busybox.net/downloads/binaries/latest/busybox-armv6l) if you don't have it yet. Of course if you don't know yet how to do it make sure you read guides or tutorials as to not break your android system. Hint: I installed mine as `/system/xbin/busybox`.

Comment: I'm not sure how you can be assumptive that `busyboxy` is truly not supported in Android.

Comment: its supported but he need solution without using busybox :)

Comment: Not if he didn't make a reason: My requirement is to list all the directory present in particular directory recursively without using find, busybox, egrep. **Because these things are not supported in android.** No need give to a negative just for that reason, but I don't mind really.

Comment: But solution is possible without any Busybox command so you should give your answer appropriately

Comment: Solution is possible but is dirty or is a hack. No better solution can be made with `find`.

Comment: This is so noobish. Let's end the discussion.

Comment: Then you should mention that look this is not solution as you want but its possible using Busybox's commands

Answer (score 0):

You can try print command to print directories

```
print  */*
```

Comment: Yes. Definitely tested it. `print` is not around.

Answer (score 0):

This lists only the directories

```
ls -FR / | grep /$
```

This lists everything about everything:

```
ls -FlatrR /
```

The "-F" flag adds a trailing flag to the files it lists, with "/" being the flag it adds on the end of directory entries.

Answer (score -1):

To list directories on the device we can us

adb shell ls -l /

Comment: ls -l list files and directory and its not recursive